# Something wrong with Python class Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm taking a Programming class, and for one of the tests I need to make a class that inherits from an already created class. This is the code the teacher taught me to do, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
class Intern(Employer):
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name, address, phone, email, end_date):
        Employer(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
        self.end_date=end_date
    def intern_info(self):
        self.print_info()
        print self.end_date
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "doesn't seem to be working".

Comment: If that's what the teacher taught you to do, he's incompetent. More likely, you missed a crucial piece.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to print the attributes from the Employer class with "self.print_info()" then print the new end_date attribute

Comment: Semantically, it doesn't even make sense to have an "Intern" inherit from an "Employer".

Comment: when I try to use the self.print_info(), it says: AttributeError: Intern instance has no attribute 'last_name'

Comment: You should check the implementation of print_info() in Employer class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
Employer(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
```

creates an `Employer` object that is immediately garbage-collected as the execution of `__init__()` ends. It does not affect the `Intern` object in any way. What you mean is probably something like

```
Employer.__init__(self, last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
```

or maybe

```
super(Intern, self).__init__(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
```

Comment: I tried creating an object from that and it said: File "<pyshell#167>", line 3, in __init__
    super(Employer, self).__init__(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: @JoshLivingston You can probably work around this if you define the `Employer` class as `class Employer(object): ...`. This way `Employer` will be a [*new style class*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/1258041), which is what you should use when writing new code.

Comment: Okay, I did the Employer.__init__(self, last_name...) and it worked. Now, I need help with the function below it, def intern_info(self):... it should take the print_info() function from the Employer class, which prints last_name, first_name, and all of the other attributes from Employer. It gives me this error when I call the intern_info() function: AttributeError: Intern instance has no attribute 'print_info'

Comment: @JoshLivingston The code you show in the question should work assuming that you defined `print_info()` in the `Employer` class.

Comment: I hope you meant `super(Intern, self).__init__(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)` for the last one. You need to pass the current class as the first parameter and super will find the next base from it, if you pass `Employer` to super you'll bypass `Employer`'s `__init__`.

Comment: @Duncan Thank you, I tend to mix that up since the first time I read the docs and was confused as to why I need to pass the object's class if I pass the object anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `self` in the arguments to `Employer`.  You either need to use `super` or pass `self` explicitly to the parent's `__init__`.  You also need to explicitly call the parent's `__init__` method.

```
class Intern(Employer):
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name, address, phone, email, end_date):
        Employer.__init__(self, last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
        self.end_date=end_date
    def intern_info(self):
        self.print_info()
        print self.end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the indentation which is the mechanism for code block in Python.

Try:

```
class Intern(Employer):
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name, address, phone, email, end_date):
        Employer(last_name, first_name, address, phone, email)
        self.end_date=end_date
    def intern_info(self):
        self.print_info()
        print self.end_date
```

Comment: That's not the sole problem though, and unlikely to be the one OP is actually facing.

Comment: I fixed it, it just messed up when I pasted the program

Comment: @delnan You know, I would have fixed my post but people here are just too quick!